# JPA Criteria based query that INTERSECTS three queries at once

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I want to find all "a" that have "b" = 500 and "b" = 501 and "c" = 2 installed. 
[image: my three tables]

In `SQL` I would do it like this:

```
select a from table1 where id in (select info_id from table2 where b = '500')
intersect
select a from table1 where id in (select info_id from table2 where b = '501')
intersect
select a from table1 where id in (select info_id from table2 where id in (select ecu_id from table3        where c = '2'));
```

So I would create three `SQL` queries and then take the intersection of those 3.
But I now have to use `JPA criteria` based queries, no native `SQL` or `JPQL`.

We could do three distinct `JPA criteria` based queries:

one that returns a list of "a" where "b" = 500,

one that returns a list of "a" where "b" = 501 and

one that returns a list of "a" where "c" = 2.

And then filter for all "a" that appear in all three returned lists. But that would take too long, our database contains many million "a" entries...

Comment: I think this link can help you. https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/where#WHERE_Filter_in_Multi_Variable_Queries

Comment: You can create 3 `subqueries` and then use `criteriaBuilder.exists(subquery)` predicates. More info here https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/criteria-api-exists-method.html

Comment: thank you both, I was able now to replace the `intersect` command with three `subqueries` connected with `where`and `exists` in SQL. I will try now to translate that in `criteriaBuilder`and post the solution, if it works...

Comment: I don't have the JPA Criteria Queria Solution yet, but the SQL with Exist Subqueries is working now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60739497/i-need-an-jpa-sql-expert-exists-query-on-an-inner-join-returns-wrong-result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is one solution in SQL:
http://tpcg.io/mV3rZ2Of

This is very long as a JPA Criteria Query, so I only show how I translated the last `Exists` condition, which was the hardest part:

```
Subquery<Table3> subQuery = searchQuery.subquery(Table3.class);
Root<Table3> fromTable3SubQuery = subQuery.from(Table3.class);
List<Predicate> subRestrictions = new ArrayList<>();

Subquery<Table2> subQueryForInExpression = searchQuery.subquery(Table2.class);
Root<Table2> fromTable2SubQuery = subQueryForInExpression.from(Table2.class);
subQueryForInExpression.select(fromTable2SubQuery.get(ID)).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(fromTable2SubQuery.get(info_id), root.get(ID)));

subRestrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(fromTable3SubQuery.get(c), '2'));
subRestrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.in(fromTable3SubQuery.get(ecu_id)).value(subQueryForInExpression));

restrictions.add(criteriaBuilder.exists(subQuery.select(
                    fromTable3SubQuery.get(c)).where(
                            subRestrictions.toArray(new Predicate[0]))));
```

-> This represents only the last `Exists`part, which is asking for the c = '2' connection. The others are similar, but without the `subQueryForInExpression` parts...

Comment: This is where I found the solution for the `SubQueryForInExpression`, which is needed for the `In`statement in the `Exists` part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758439/problem-with-translating-sql-in-subquery-into-a-jpa-criteria-query/60762875#60762875