# I need an JPA/SQL expert: EXISTS query on an Inner Join returns wrong result

Tags: sql, jpa, subquery, exists, intersect

I have three tables and want to:

`Select` all students `from` the first table,

that have at least one connection to the school in district '999' in the second table

`and` at least one connection to the teacher with social_number '101'

`and` at least one to the teacher with number '103' in the third table.

The tables are connected through the second table.

[image: my three tables]

I created an online sql compiler to show the problem:
http://tpcg.io/FIoO79xi

This query works fine and as expected, until I add the third `EXISTS` Command where I search for a connection to teacher '103'. Then it doesn't return student A anymore, altough he has a connection to teacher '103'

I found a workaround by adding `joins` in the `Exists sub-query`: 
http://tpcg.io/0sza7t5g
but since my real database tables have many million entries, this would lead to joining the three tables in every row that the `sub-query` goes through and this can take very long if it only finds a fitting entry at the end of the table.

I think the problem is here at the `sub-query`: `WHERE th1.school_id = th.school_id` where I'm trying to find a connection from the third table teacher to the at the beginning joined together table. If I search for a connection to teacher 102 instead of 103, the query works and returns student A: 
http://tpcg.io/2tHIEk3V 
Because teacher 101 and 102 have the same school_id.

But how can I write that differently so that the query also finds student A when I search for a connection to teacher 101 and 103? Student A has a connection to both, so it should be possible somehow with exists...

Add: I can't use three seperate queries and then use the `Intersect` command on them, since I'm translating that `SQL` into a `JPA` query. `JPA`doesn`t know intersect...

Comment: If you don't want a SQL solution, you need a JPA expert, not a SQL expert

Comment: Yes, haha, sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st condition:

> at least one connection to the school in district '999' in the second
>   table

needs a join of `student` to `school`.
The 2nd and 3rd conditions:

> at least one connection to the teacher with social_number '101'
>   and  at least one to the teacher with number '103'

need 2 **separate** joins of `student` to `school` and `teacher`:

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM student s
INNER JOIN school sc on s.student_id = sc.student_id AND sc.district = 999
INNER JOIN school sc1 on s.student_id = sc1.student_id
INNER JOIN teacher t1 on t1.school_id = sc1.school_id AND t1.social_number = 101
INNER JOIN school sc2 on s.student_id = sc2.student_id
INNER JOIN teacher t2 on t2.school_id = sc2.school_id AND t2.social_number = 103
```

Note that a condition like `social_number in (101, 103)` will not work because it would return results even if only 1 of the conditions was satisfied. 
This is why you need 2 joins to `school` and `teacher`.
Also all the joins must be `inner` because you want to satisfy all 3 conditions.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ndyfNJZMf9xccSp98z8o24/1).
Results:

```
| name |
| ---- |
| A    |
```

Comment: Great answer. This should work perfectly and looks more tidy than using EXISTS

Comment: This is great thank you! When I saw your answer I thought, it's maybe too many joins for our database and then found a dirfferent solution with a colleauge, but I will try yours tomorrow on our database, maybe it's faster.

Comment: This solution was faster than the one with exists subqueries on our database.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 teacher table joins

```
SELECT name 
FROM student
left JOIN school sc1 on #student.student_id = sc1.student_id
left JOIN teacher th1 on sc1.school_id = th1.school_id and th1.social_number=101
left JOIN teacher th2 on sc1.school_id = th2.school_id and th1.social_number=103
where sc1.district=999
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. I will try the working answers tomorrow and see which one is faster on our database.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated ?

```
`SELECT name 
FROM student
LEFT JOIN school sc1 on student.student_id = sc1.student_id
LEFT JOIN teacher th1 on sc1.school_id = th1.school_id
WHERE sc1.district = '999'
AND th1.social_number in('101','103')`
```

doesn't do the trick ?

Comment: This will not work because the teacher match is not the same as the school match...I guess this is exactly what OP has tried.

Comment: thank you, but as COY said, this wouldn't work exactly as I intended...

Answer (score 0):

http://tpcg.io/eGeWjkOf

The whole joining is unnecessary when we ask for a connection between the teacher and the student in an additional `WHERE` clause.
The `Exists subquery` then looks like this, instead of a Join I use an additional `where` to make sure the teacher.school_id is the same as the school.school_id of the school the student goes to:

```
EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM teacher th
WHERE th.social_number = '103'
AND th.school_id in (SELECT school_id FROM school WHERE student_id = student.student_id ))
```